# Echo canceler using auto correlation

Tags: matlab

I am implementing an echo canceler by first finding the parameters for the echoed signal using auto correlation. I have multiple delays in my signal.
After using s=xcorr(x,x), how do I extract the values of the peaks of s? The max function gives the value at the center of s, and findpeaks() gives values of peaks that lie just next to the maximum peak, but higher than the real delay peaks.

Comment: Have you tried any of the available `findpeaks` options, for example `minpeakdistance` or `threshold`?

Answer (score 1):

**In short**

Use findpeaks with SORTSTR applied on a smoothed version of your autocorrelation.

**In more words**

It really depends how noisy your signal is but a quick solution to your problem is to first smooth your autocorrelation to limit the effect of noise, which may introduce multiple local maxima around the peaks of interest.  Then you can take the peaks sorted in decreasing order.

Other options to play with and possibly combine:

- 'MINPEAKHEIGHT' to find peaks that are above a threshold (say above 10% of the max of your autocorrelation)
- 'MINPEAKDISTANCE' to avoid local maxima too close to each other

Or just write you own code, which is what you may need to do ultimately to get the code to do exactly what you want.

**In code:**

```
% Create right portion of autocorrelation of a sinusoid with some noise
% This should lead to peaks of decreasing amplitude around positions 1, 26, 51, 76
% Note: This is a quick example.  A more realistic signal would show better peaks.
x=.4*sin(2*pi*(1:N)/N*4)+rand(1,N);
autocorr=xcorr(x);
autocorr=autocorr(N:(2*N-1));

% Smooth out the autocorrelation
autocorrFiltered=filter([1 1 1 1 1],[1],autocorr);
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(autocorr);
xlabel('Autocorrelation')
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(autocorrFiltered);
xlabel('Smoothed autocorrelation')
[peaks,locations]=findpeaks(autocorrFiltered,'SORTSTR','descend');

% Display locations, correcting for the filter offset
locations-3
ans =

      2    23    49    73    92
```

**In image:**

Here is the comparison of filter and unfiltered autocorr side by side illustrating why the smoothing helps with finding the peaks.

[image]